# Multi line text renderer with dynamic JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm doing a java project in which i have to display inside a JTable a list of articles taken from the web with jsoup. The problem of multiline text renderer is not new and I've already faced it in other post(for example this http://blog.botunge.dk/post/2009/10/09/JTable-multiline-cell-renderer.aspx). But in this problem the table is static, the number of rows is fixed at first and it remains the same. In my project the initial number of rows are one and editing a query in cell (0,0) the table should update by showing in new rows the list of articles(with title, content, data and link to the article).
Here's the code of main class:

```
public class ClientGrafico {
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedOperationException{

    JTable table = new JTable();
    table.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, new MultiLineTableCellRenderer1());
    table.setModel(TabellaDati.getTabellaDati());
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableDemo");
    frame.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //display the window
    frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
    }
 }
```

here's is code of class MultiLineTableCellRenderer1:

```
public class MultiLineTableCellRenderer1 extends JTextArea 
implements TableCellRenderer {
  private ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> rowColHeight = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>      ();

  public MultiLineTableCellRenderer1() {
    setLineWrap(true);
    setWrapStyleWord(true);
    setOpaque(true);
  }

  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,int row, int column) {
    if (isSelected) {
      setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
      setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
    } else {
      setForeground(table.getForeground());
      setBackground(table.getBackground());
    }
    setFont(table.getFont());
    if (hasFocus) {
      setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("Table.focusCellHighlightBorder"));
      if (table.isCellEditable(row, column)) {
        setForeground(UIManager.getColor("Table.focusCellForeground"));
        setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Table.focusCellBackground"));
      }
    } else {
      setBorder(new EmptyBorder(1, 2, 1, 2));
    }
    if (value != null) {
      setText(value.toString());
    } else {
      setText("");
    }
    adjustRowHeight(table, row, column);
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Calculate the new preferred height for a given row, and sets the height on the    table.*/
  private void adjustRowHeight(JTable table, int row, int column) {
    //The trick to get this to work properly is to set the width of the column to the 
    //textarea. The reason for this is that getPreferredSize(), without a width tries 
    //to place all the text in one line. By setting the size with the with of the  column, 
    //getPreferredSize() returnes the proper height which the row should have in
    //order to make room for the text.
    int cWidth = table.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getWidth();
    setSize(new Dimension(cWidth, 1000));
    int prefH = getPreferredSize().height;
    while (rowColHeight.size() <= row) {
      rowColHeight.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(column));
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> colHeights = rowColHeight.get(row);
    while (colHeights.size() <= column) {
      colHeights.add(0);
    }
    colHeights.set(column, prefH);
    int maxH = prefH;
    for (Integer colHeight : colHeights) {
      if (colHeight > maxH) {
        maxH = colHeight;
      }
    }
    if (table.getRowHeight(row) != maxH) {
      table.setRowHeight(row, maxH);
    }
  }
}
```

here's the code for the model of the table:

```
public class TabellaDati extends AbstractTabellaDati{

  private EditListener listener;
  private WriteListener listener1;
  private String[] nomi_colonne;
  private ArrayList<Article> dati;

  public TabellaDati(){
    nomi_colonne = new String[]{"Titolo","Articolo","Data","Link all'articolo"};
    dati= new ArrayList<Article>();
    listener = new EditListener(this);
    listener1 = new WriteListener(this);
    //for(int i=0;i <20; i++)
    dati.add(new Article()); //aggiunta di un articolo vuoto per creare la prima riga della tabella
    this.setValueAt("PRESS TO UPDATE", 0, 1);
  }

  public static AbstractTabellaDati getTabellaDati()
  {
    return new TabellaDati();
  }

  public void riempi_tabella (String token)
  {
    /*rimuove tutte le righe tranne la prima*/
    int data_size = dati.size();
    for(int k=1; k< data_size;++k)
      dati.remove(1);
    Document ciao = null;
    estrazioneDati extr = new estrazioneDati();
    try {
      ciao=extr.connessione(token);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ArrayList<String> a1= extr.titoli_articoli(ciao);
    ArrayList<String> a2= extr.parte_articoli(ciao);
    ArrayList<String> a3= extr.data_notizia(ciao);
    ArrayList<String> a4= extr.link_art(ciao);

    for(int j=0;j<extr.return_count();j++)
      this.addArticle(new Article(a1.get(j),a2.get(j),a3.get(j),a4.get(j)));

  }

  public void addArticle(Article c) {
    this.dati.add(c);
  }

  public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex,int columnIndex)
  {
    if(rowIndex==0)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }

  public int getRowCount()
  {
    return dati.size();
  } 

  public int getColumnCount()
  {
    return nomi_colonne.length;
  }

  public String getColumnName(int columnIndex)
  {
    return nomi_colonne[columnIndex];      
  }

  public Class<?> getColumnClass(int c) {
    return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
  }

  public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex){
    Article ar = dati.get(rowIndex);
    /*switch(columnIndex){
      case(0): 
        return ar.getTitle();
      case(1):
        return ar.getContent();
      case(2):
        return ar.getDate();
      case(3):
        return ar.getLink();
      default:
        return null;
      }*/

    if(columnIndex==0)
      return ar.getTitle();
    else if(columnIndex==1)
      return ar.getContent();
    else if(columnIndex==2)
      return ar.getDate();
    else if(columnIndex==3)
      return ar.getLink();
    return null;


  }

  public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex){
    Article ar = dati.get(rowIndex);
    String str = (String)aValue;
    /*switch(columnIndex){
      case(0): 
        ar.setTitle(str);
        break;
      case(1):
        ar.setContent(str);
        break;
      case(2):
        ar.setDate(str);
        break;
      case(3):
        ar.setLink(str);
          break;
      }*/

    if(columnIndex==0)
      ar.setTitle(str);
    else if(columnIndex==1)
      ar.setContent(str);
    else if(columnIndex==2)
      ar.setDate(str);
    else if(columnIndex==3)
      ar.setLink(str);


    /*---Con TableModelListener---*/
    TableModelEvent event = new TableModelEvent(this, rowIndex, rowIndex, columnIndex, TableModelEvent.UPDATE);
    if(rowIndex+columnIndex==0) 
      listener.tableChanged(event);


    /*---Con ChangeListener---*/
    /*ChangeEvent event = new ChangeEvent(this);
      if(rowIndex+columnIndex==0)
        listener1.stateChanged(event);*/

  }

  public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener l){
  }

  public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener l){
  }
}
```

here's the code for class AbstractTabellaDati:

```
 public abstract class AbstractTabellaDati implements TableModel{
/* Da utilizzare per creare oggetti (no costruttori) */
public static AbstractTabellaDati getTabellaDati() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("da implementare");
}

/* Restituisce true se la cella in posizione
(rowIndex,columnIndex) è modificabile. Deve restituire sempre true
per tutte le celle con rowIndex == 0 */
abstract public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex);
}
```

here's the code for class Article:

```
 public class Article {

private String title;
private String content;
private String date;
private String link;

public Article()
{
    this("", "", "","");
}

public Article(String title, String content, String date, String link)
{
    this.title = title;
    this.content = content;
    this.date = date;
    this.link = link;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
}

public String getLink() {
    return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
        this.date = link;
}
}
```

here's the code for class EditListener:

```
 public class EditListener implements TableModelListener 
 /*per la gestione degli eventi tramite TableModelListener*/
 {
private TabellaDati tab;

public EditListener(TabellaDati tab){
    this.tab=tab;
}

public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
    //if(e.getColumn() + e.getFirstRow() ==0) {
        String keyword= tab.getValueAt(0,0).toString();
        System.out.println(keyword);
        tab.riempi_tabella(keyword);
    //}
    //TabellaDati.getTabellaDati();
}

}
```

here's the code for class estrazioneDati:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public  class estrazioneDati {   

  private int count;
  private ArrayList<String> titolo_pronto;
  private ArrayList<String> testo_articolo;
  private ArrayList<String>  dataEora;
  private ArrayList<String> link_articolo;

  public estrazioneDati(){
    count=0;
    titolo_pronto= new ArrayList<String>();
    testo_articolo=new ArrayList<String>();
    dataEora=new ArrayList<String>();
    link_articolo=new ArrayList<String>();
  }

  public Document connessione(String richiesta) throws IOException
  {

    if(richiesta.equalsIgnoreCase("Sport")){
      Document doc= Jsoup.connect("http://www.unionesarda.it/sport").get();
      return doc;
    }
    else if(richiesta.equalsIgnoreCase("Sardegna")){
      Document doc= Jsoup.connect("http://www.unionesarda.it/cronaca_sardegna").get();
      return doc;
    }
    else if(richiesta.equalsIgnoreCase("Cronaca")){
      Document doc= Jsoup.connect("http://www.unionesarda.it/cronaca_italiana").get();
      return doc;
    }
    else if(richiesta.equalsIgnoreCase("Spettacolo")){
      Document doc= Jsoup.connect("http://www.unionesarda.it/spettacoli_e_cultura").get();
      return doc;
    }
    else if(richiesta.equalsIgnoreCase("Politica")){
      Document doc=
          Jsoup.connect("http://www.unionesarda.it/politica_italiana").get();
      return doc;
    }
    else if(richiesta.equalsIgnoreCase("Esteri") || richiesta.equalsIgnoreCase("Estero")){
      Document doc= Jsoup.connect("http://www.unionesarda.it/notizie_mondo").get();
      return doc;
    }
    else if(richiesta.equalsIgnoreCase("Economia")){
      Document doc= Jsoup.connect("http://www.unionesarda.it/notizie_economia").get();
      return doc;
    }
    return null;
  }

  public ArrayList<String> titoli_articoli(Document doc)
  {
    Elements titoli=doc.select("[class^=box_elenco_titolo] > a");
    for(Element titolo : titoli) {
      titolo_pronto.add(titolo.attr("title"));
      count ++;
    }

    return titolo_pronto;
  }

  public ArrayList<String> parte_articoli(Document doc) 
  {
    Elements parte_articolo= doc.select("[class^=georgia font15 interlinea20]");
    for(Element titolo : parte_articolo)
      testo_articolo.add(titolo.text());

    return testo_articolo;
  }     

  public ArrayList<String> data_notizia(Document doc)
  {
    Elements data_ora= doc.select("span.ora_notizia");
    for(Element time : data_ora)
      dataEora.add(time.text());

    return dataEora;  
  }

  public ArrayList<String> link_art(Document doc)
  {
    Elements link=doc.select("[class^=box_elenco_titolo] > a");
    for(Element colleg : link )
      link_articolo.add(colleg.attr("href"));

    return link_articolo;
  }

  public int return_count()
  {
    return count;
  }     
}
```

the software runs correctly but i'm not able to update the table in such a way that new rows appears to display the dati inside ArrayList dati, which is update whenever a query in cell (0,0) is performed.
Anyone has an idea?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Only thing that I don't see in your code is where you tell your table that you added data to it. As Andrew said, a SSCCE would help greatly.

Comment: your setup looks fishy: the editListener is listening (to what exactly?) and updates the tableModel (which?) Typically, the model cares for itself.

Comment: the editListener method tableChanged() is called from setValueAt only when there's a change in cell (0,0) and call the method riempi_tabella() in order to update the ArrayList dati. Is there another way to implement the listener?

Comment: tableChanged is a method of a TableModel-**Listener** , not the TableModel - it's the task of the model itself to send a TableModelEvent on setValueAt and a listener **must not** change the state of the source of the sender. Time for a step back and some tutorial reading, f.i. the online tutorial referenced in the swing tag wiki

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jonathan that I don't see in your code where to add row.

Try to add the below line in your code after adding the row.
tableModel.fireTableRowsInserted(tableData.size() - 1, tableData.size() - 1);

Comment: no, **never-ever** do any firing on behalf of the model, that's the inherent task of the model itself, that is somewhere _inside_ the model-method that actually to insert rows the fireInserted must be called, nowhere else.

Comment: the class Tabella dati implements the interface TableModel, not AbstractTableModel, so i cant' use fireTableRowsInserted. However i've tried to change the interface in AbstractTableModel and don't works anyway

Comment: @hellbago that's rather suboptimal not to extend from AbstractTableModel (as it does provided the methods that your custom implementation can use to correctly notify its listeners) - if you insist you have to implement those (or similar) methods yourself. Which means duplicating code, always a strong fishy smell ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If I don't use a custom renderer the software works nice, but of course i can't obtain the wrapped text inside the cells. So the problems seems to appear with a custom renderer, in this case implemented in the class MultiLineTableRenderer. With a custom renderer the Jtable seems not to understand that the number of rows of rows changes dinamically.